# Typo3: Languages have no isoCodeA2

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

I've installed the language Selection Plugin (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sr_language_menu/) and I'm trying to showing the Selection Widget in my .html-File, so far it works and my languages get shown in the selection dropdown, but I'm also trying to show a flag next to my language, which only works for my Default Language (DE) but for no other language I add.

I've put the widget in my html:

```
{namespace languageMenu=SJBR\SrLanguageMenu\ViewHelpers}
<languageMenu:widget.menu languages="0,2,3" layout="Select" languageTitle="1" />
```

and whenever I debug what my Options in the select return I receive this:

This is for DE my default language:

```
   option => array(9 items)
      uid => 0 (integer)
      isoCodeA2 => 'DE' (2 chars)
      countryIsoCodeA2 => '' (0 chars)
      combinedIsoCode => 'de' (2 chars)
      title => 'Deutsch' (7 chars)
      flagFile => 'typo3conf/ext/sr_language_menu/Resources/Public/Images/Flags/de.png' (67 chars)
      isAvailable => TRUE
      notAvailableTitle => 'Deutsch' (7 chars)
      isCurrent => TRUE
```

As you can see `isoCodeA2` is available, so `combinedIsoCode` is created and thus `flagFile` gets the right `de.png`

But for my second language I get this back:

```
   option => array(9 items)
      uid => 2 (integer)
      isoCodeA2 => '' (0 chars)
      countryIsoCodeA2 => '' (0 chars)
      combinedIsoCode => '' (0 chars)
      title => 'Deutsch (einfach)' (17 chars)
      flagFile => 'typo3conf/ext/sr_language_menu/Resources/Public/Images/Flags/.png' (65 chars)
      isAvailable => TRUE
      notAvailableTitle => 'Deutsch (einfach)' (17 chars)
      isCurrent => TRUE
```

As you can see this language does not have an `isoCodeA2` and thus no `combinedIsoCode` and the `flagFile` only links to an empty .png

My Question would be now how can I set the `isoCodeA2` for any other language than my default language? It doesn't matter which or how many other languages I create, they never have this `isoCodeA2` in their options.

I'm using Typo3 9.5.18 with Docker. Any help is appreciated!

config.yaml:

```
base: /
baseVariants: {}
errorHandling:
  - errorCode: "404"
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: "t3://page?uid=20"
languages:
  - title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ""
    flag: de
    languageId: "0"
  - title: Deutsch_vereinfacht
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch_vereinfacht
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ""
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: "2"
    flag: de
    languageId: "2"
rootPageId: 18
routes: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Language creation is one thing you must do. The other one is language configuration.

The first is done with records in the global root page.

The other is done in the site configuration (and the data is stored in `/config/sites/mydomin/config.yaml`). here you enter the ISO code.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did (see updated config.yaml code)